# Как обновить TextView из другого потока?

Tags: android, многопоточность, textview

Кажется всё понятным но не получается самое главное обновить Text в MainActivity.

Принятые данные от bluetooth. Имею следующее: Есть главная активити в которой пару кнопок. Поиск устройств / сопряжение и т.д. - это работает. Так же есть кнопка отправить данные: тоже работает.

Но при подключении к устройству (серверу) я в классе Connect запуская новый поток Класса Read. То есть когда я отображаю главную активити у меня всё время крутится поток в классе READ который ждёт приходящие данные - с этим он успешно справляется и все получает. Но вот как мне их вывести в TextView в Main  я так и не понял. Я создавал в Main - Handler

```java
Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage: "+msg.what);
        switch (msg.what){
            case 5:
                Log.d(TAG, "handleMessageObj: "+msg.obj);
                Data=msg.what;
               getTextView.setText(msg.what);
        }
    }
};
```

Если я в него отправляю данные из MAIN просто самостоятельно для теста то всё работает и TextView заполняется данными. Но как мне в него отправить данные из потока другого класса Read? Если я туда передам из главной Activity этот handler то данные я получаю в главном цикле  public void handleMessage Но при попытке записать их в getTextView.setText(msg.what); Получаю ошибку: С элементами можно работать только из родного потока. Вот тут я не могу понять. Надеюсь хорошо расписал. Очень надеюсь на ответ. Спасибо.

Comment: Покажите как вы его вызываете в другом классе. Должно быть примерно так: `handler.obtainMessage(what, obj).sendToTarget();`

Comment: в потоке класса Read я его вызваю так  msg = h.obtainMessage(5,takenData);
                        h.sendMessage(msg);

Comment: Тогда у вас 100% другая ошибка, а именно `setText(msg.what);` - здесь вы передаёте не строку, а число 5 и метод пытается найти в ресурсах строку с id=5, которой наверняка не существует.

Comment: даже если я тут пишу setText("любой мой текст"); то ошибка всё равно. проблемма не в том что я туда пытаюсь записать а в потоке.

Comment: Тогда показывайте лог ошибки и код создания, передачи и вызова хандлера.

Comment: ответил внизу ответом на свой вопрос. сюда не поместилось

Comment: Droid, всю дополнительную информацию следует писать не в комментариях и тем более не в ответах - а в самом вопросе. Для этого под вопросом есть кнопка [`Править`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1443091/edit) Если вы создали другой хандлер, то он другой и очередь у него своя собственная, и колбек у каждого свой. Вы представляете что бы было, если бы все хандлеры в системе получали ваши сообщения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы ваш код отработал, нужно у объекта `Handler` вызвать метод `post`, куда передать экземпляр `Runnable`:

```java
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText("Hello World");
    }
});
```

То же самое можно написать покороче, если воспользоваться методом `runOnUiThread`:

```java
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText("Hello World");
    }
});
```

Или, используя лямбды:

```java
runOnUiThread(() -> {
    textView.setText("Hello World");
});
```

Comment: в run класса Read я обращаюсь по сути к mHandler который был создан в main. В main слушатель принимает сообщения но при попытке из слушателя обновить Text матюкает что нужно обновлять только из родного потока. Но по сути main же и есть родной потоке. в потоке Read я только же посылаю ему сообщение как бы самому себе. Да наверно сильно запутанно все. Ну тоесть я не могу вызвать runOnUiThread(new Runnable() из за того что mHandler был создан еще в main и я его передаю через конструктор 2 раза до точки назначения. Запутал наверно очень я.

Comment: Объект я же создаю в Main или в неём нужно :  при приеме нужно запускать еще раз поток для обновления активити? Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage: "+msg.what);
            switch (msg.what){
                case 5:
                    Log.d(TAG, "handleMessageObj: "+msg.obj);
                    Data=msg.what;
                   getTextView.setText(Data);
            }
        }
    };

Comment: А можете создать `Handler mainHandler = ...` (на main looper), потом его передать куда нужно. И далее над этим `handler` запускать любые `runnable` и взаимодействовать с вьюхами: `mainHandler.post(() -> textView.setText("Hello"));`. Так не выйдет?

Comment: Спасибо заработало у меня просто передачей хандлера по классам. к сожалению не понял что сразу писал не так. Где ошибся. Пока работает) Всем спасибо за ответы!!!

Comment: @Droid, eсли мой ответ вам подошел, то вы можете отметить его правильным, нажав на галочку слева от ответа.